# KML coordinates

Tags: coordinates, kml

I was trying to figure out coordinate point from latitude/longitude, and already try many sites, but it is still not working. Below is the place I would like to get coordinate point, and thank you so much if you can help. Please also let me know how to get it by converting lat/lon, or other ways to get it. Thank you so much, Love!

338 A2 Park Mead, London, UK
Latitude: 51.507628
Longitude: -0.153378

KT

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the street address then entering the address in a KML file launches Google Earth with that address. In Google Earth, you can mouse over the location and see the coordinates at the bottom of the map (Status Bar must be checked in View menu). If you save the placemark in your My Places (or to a new file), then you'll notice Google Earth fills in the latitude and longitude coordinates for that location.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Placemark>
        <name>place</name>
        <address>338 A2 Park Mead, London, UK</address>
    </Placemark>
</kml>
```

If you already have the coordinates then you can create a KML placemark in Google Earth by [creating a new Placemark](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148142?hl=en) and filling in the latitude and longitude values. Otherwise, you can create a small KML file with the latitude and longitude coordinates. Note coordinates must appear as longitude, latitude (in that order) and be in decimal degrees.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Placemark>
        <name>place</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-0.153378,51.507628</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</kml>
```